# How to make equation formulas reactive in shiny R?

Tags: r, text, shiny, formula, reactive

I have some text and I want to put inline formulas which may change when modifying some inputs of a shiny app. I know how to change text dynamically using HTML:

```
        
        tags$h4("Statistical hypothesis testing"),
        HTML(paste0("<b>", "H", tags$sub(0), "</b>", ": the variables ", "<b>", input$categorical1, "</b>", " and ", "<b>", input$categorical2, "</b>", " are independent")),
        HTML(paste(br())),
        HTML(paste0("<b>", "H", tags$sub(1), "</b>", ": the variables ", "<b>", input$categorical1, "</b>", " and ", "<b>", input$categorical2, "</b>", " are not independent")),
        
      )
```

but with HTML I cannot introduce some formulas with summations (as far as I know, if there is a way of introducing complex formulas using tags would be fine).

In the other hand I have found a way of writing complex formulas inline some text, but in this case I cannot change dynamically the text like in HTML.

Comment: Perhaps  have a look at [MatJax](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/mathjax.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try `renderUI`/`uiOutput`:

```
    tags$h4("Statistical hypothesis testing"),
    uiOutput("html")
```

in server:

```
output[["html"]] <- renderUI({
  tagList(
        HTML(paste0("<b>", "H", tags$sub(0), "</b>", ": the variables ", "<b>", input$categorical1, "</b>", " and ", "<b>", input$categorical2, "</b>", " are independent")),
        HTML(paste(br())),
        HTML(paste0("<b>", "H", tags$sub(1), "</b>", ": the variables ", "<b>", input$categorical1, "</b>", " and ", "<b>", input$categorical2, "</b>", " are not independent"))
  )
})
```